# Flutter - How to view Prefix on TextFormField even not pressed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Im new to flutter, i want to view the prefix text in textformfield even not on pressed.
My code:

```
TextFormField(
 decoration: InputDecoration(
   prefix: Text("Subject: ",
     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
   hintText: "Unique Subject",
   border: OutlineInputBorder(),
),
```

Sorry for the img link, im still new to stackoverflow still havent reached 10 reputations.

This is my result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoYLY.png)

This is what i want, even textformfield havent been pressed

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o45DU.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few workarounds for this.
To know more use this as reference: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19488

```
prefixIcon: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                      child: Text('Subject:',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
                    )
                  ],),
                  hintText: "Unique Subject",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
```

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 0):

add this in your TextFormField

```
'prefix: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 15, vertical: 20),
                              child: Text(
                                'Subject ',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 13.sp,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                              ),
                            ),'
```